# Как можно переместить мышку с помощью selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

Есть определенный сайт, где надо кликнуть на последнюю звездочку элемента.На странице есть скрипт который анализирует положение мышки и выводит оценку человеку.С помощью selenium click() оно не работает скорее всего что нужна реальная мышка.Как можно нажать на этот элемент чтобы он выставил нужную оценку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если надо могу приложить скрипт обработки мышки и выставлении оценки с сайта.На сайт увы вы зайти не сможете

```html
<div class="col col-auto">
  <div data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating" value="0">
    <div data-v-fde73a0c="" class="sr-only"><span data-v-fde73a0c="">Rated 0 stars out of 5</span></div>
    <div data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating"><span data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating-pointer vue-star-rating-star" style="margin-right: 0px;"><svg data-v-ef4bc576="" data-v-fde73a0c="" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="vue-star-rating-star" step="100"><linearGradient data-v-ef4bc576="" id="onct89" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><filter data-v-ef4bc576="" id="9ldi8u" height="130%" width="130%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feGaussianBlur data-v-ef4bc576="" stdDeviation="0" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur><feMerge data-v-ef4bc576=""><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><!----><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#onct89)" stroke="#999" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="miter"></polygon><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#onct89)"></polygon></svg></span>
      <span
        data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating-pointer vue-star-rating-star" style="margin-right: 0px;"><svg data-v-ef4bc576="" data-v-fde73a0c="" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="vue-star-rating-star" step="100"><linearGradient data-v-ef4bc576="" id="9ooro3" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><filter data-v-ef4bc576="" id="109l8s" height="130%" width="130%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feGaussianBlur data-v-ef4bc576="" stdDeviation="0" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur><feMerge data-v-ef4bc576=""><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><!----><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#9ooro3)" stroke="#999" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="miter"></polygon><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#9ooro3)"></polygon></svg></span>
        <span
          data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating-pointer vue-star-rating-star" style="margin-right: 0px;"><svg data-v-ef4bc576="" data-v-fde73a0c="" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="vue-star-rating-star" step="100"><linearGradient data-v-ef4bc576="" id="lcj37e" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><filter data-v-ef4bc576="" id="rvnbyi" height="130%" width="130%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feGaussianBlur data-v-ef4bc576="" stdDeviation="0" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur><feMerge data-v-ef4bc576=""><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><!----><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#lcj37e)" stroke="#999" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="miter"></polygon><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#lcj37e)"></polygon></svg></span>
          <span
            data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating-pointer vue-star-rating-star" style="margin-right: 0px;"><svg data-v-ef4bc576="" data-v-fde73a0c="" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="vue-star-rating-star" step="100"><linearGradient data-v-ef4bc576="" id="03moqk" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><filter data-v-ef4bc576="" id="q9f39n" height="130%" width="130%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feGaussianBlur data-v-ef4bc576="" stdDeviation="0" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur><feMerge data-v-ef4bc576=""><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><!----><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#03moqk)" stroke="#999" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="miter"></polygon><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#03moqk)"></polygon></svg></span>
            <span
              data-v-fde73a0c="" class="vue-star-rating-pointer vue-star-rating-star" style="margin-right: 0px;"><svg data-v-ef4bc576="" data-v-fde73a0c="" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="vue-star-rating-star" step="100"><linearGradient data-v-ef4bc576="" id="jd9uv6" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-ef4bc576="" offset="0%" stop-color="#d8d8d8" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><filter data-v-ef4bc576="" id="ox545l" height="130%" width="130%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feGaussianBlur data-v-ef4bc576="" stdDeviation="0" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur><feMerge data-v-ef4bc576=""><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode data-v-ef4bc576="" in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter><!----><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#jd9uv6)" stroke="#999" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="miter"></polygon><polygon data-v-ef4bc576="" points="13.636363636363637,1.5151515151515151,4.545454545454545,30,27.272727272727273,11.818181818181818,0,11.818181818181818,22.727272727272727,30" fill="url(#jd9uv6)"></polygon></svg></span>
              <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

код которым пытался кликнуть

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
gecko_driver_path = (r"C:\report\geckodriver.exe")
firefox_binary_path = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
firefox_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=gecko_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service, options=firefox_options)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("сайт")

element_xpath = f"/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[5]s/svg"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath)))  # нажатие kolighestfo
#action.move_to_element(element)
#action.perform()
element.click()
```

Comment: Нужна разметка ваших звездочек и код, которым вы пытаетесь отследить положени и кликнуть

Comment: @SwaD добавил информацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал немного просто но зато работает,вначале открыл сайт на полный экранзаписал координаты, добавил в celenium строчку fullscreen_window() и тыкаю мышкой через pyautogui